# Null Check Operator Used On A Null Value Error Please Solve

Tags: null

[Please Check This Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iutEp.png)

I try to solve this issue but I fail please solve this issue. Thank u

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. Exactly what trouble are you having with it?

Comment: i don't understand it how to solve this error